# Running RStudio Shiny as a Docker container on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

Has anybody looked into the possibility of running an instance of a RStudio Shiny server as a Docker container on the Amazon AWS cloud?

I have seen a document specifying how to instantiate RStudio on a different cloud provider here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/running-rstudio-via-docker-in-the-cloud
http://www.magesblog.com/2014/09/running-rstudio-via-docker-in-cloud.html

What I would like to know, more specifically, is if there are any documents explaining how to have a running instance of an RStudio Shiny server on AWS inside a Docker container, authenticated so that it can at least read files from a AWS account and use them for interactive Shiny visualizations. Beyond that also be able to write results back to EC2.

Any pointers or major technical difficulties that people anticipate?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah . See http://www.r-bloggers.com/running-rstudio-via-docker-in-the-cloud/

Using this docker image (rocker/rstudio)
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rocker/rstudio/

Comment: I think the link I provided is just a copy of the one you provide here. I added yours as well. I wonder if anybody has documented the process to have a Shiny server running on AWS inside Docker, which is a couple of steps further than the description in your URL.